# "Created slice user-0.slice." and "Starting Session 2025 of user root." in /var/log/messages

Tags: logging, systemd, centos-7

I am getting "Created slice user-0.slice."
and "Starting Session 2025 of user root." in `/var/log/messages` in CentOS 7. 
Can someone explain what they are?

```
[root@bew /]# tail -f /var/log/messages
May 26 21:20:01 bew systemd: Created slice user-0.slice.
May 26 21:20:01 bew systemd: Starting Session 2025 of user root.
May 26 21:20:01 bew systemd: Started Session 2025 of user root.
May 26 22:22:33 bew systemd: Stopping System Logging Service...
May 26 22:22:33 bew systemd: Starting System Logging Service...
May 26 22:22:33 bew systemd: Started System Logging Service.
May 26 22:30:01 bew systemd: Created slice user-0.slice.
May 26 22:30:01 bew systemd: Starting Session 2026 of user root.
May 26 22:30:01 bew systemd: Started Session 2026 of user root.
```

Comment: especially given that it times-out on debian shutdown

Answer (score 5):

These are low priority "info"-level messages related to session and resource management.  You can avoid them via

```
# systemd-analyze set-log-level notice
```

Comment: Do these message mean that there was a successful login for user root?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823),

> These messages are normal and expected -- they will be seen any time a user
>   logs in.

If you don’t want to see these messages, Red Hat propose an alternate solution to prevent them from being logged while still keeping other `info`-level messages from the `systemd` service:

1. Modify `rsyslog` to create a discard filter by running the following
   command:

   ```
   echo 'if $programname == "systemd" and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session" or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-") then stop' >/etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf
   ```
2. Restart the `rsyslog` service:

   ```
   systemctl restart rsyslog
   ```

Comment: Had to change if statement to `if $programname contains "systemd"` because program name is called `systemd-logind`